# In Spring boot, Is there a master annotation to specify basePackages for scanning components, repositories, entities, etc

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

Problem:

I had to write different annotations for different types of objects like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.dbs.ntb.remittance" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.dbs.ntb.remittance" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.dbs.ntb.remittance" })
public class Application {
```

Is there a master annotation, something like:

```
@Scan(basePackages = {"com.dbs.ntb.remittance"})
```

Update :
I saw @SpringBootApplication has this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.dbs.ntb.remittance" })
public class Application {
```

But it only is an alias for @ComponentScan. It doesn't scan repositories and entities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `@SpringBootApplication` will do all this for you. If you place the `@SpringBootApplication` in the root package it will pickup  JPA repositories, find entities, and components for you.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

You could make a Meta Annotation to at least enforce all the scans have been set.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan()
public @interface Scan {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ComponentScan.class, attribute = "basePackages") String[] scanBasePackages();

    @AliasFor(annotation = EntityScan.class, attribute = "basePackages") String[] scanEntities();

}
```

I've omitted the @EnableJPARepositories, this will at least force you to set the values for each scan, but I'd recommend having the boot app in the root of the package structure.

Comment: Was just about to update my question :
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.dbs.ntb.remittance" }) is just an alias for @componentScan. Its not working for repositories and entities. Will update my question with this info

Comment: No it won't, it is generally best practice to just place the SpringBootApplication in the root of the package structure or else you will fall into configuration over convention. You could make a meta annotation to clean it up slightly in my example, but the `AliasFor` annotation isn't repetable so you cannot feed values to multiple annotations from one field.

Comment: OK. I understood now. Yes it will ofcourse work if this annotation is in the base package already. Question is when we don't have the boot start class in the root package already

Comment: Yeah you have no choice but to do this, I added an example of a meta annotation you could create to try and clean it up.

Comment: I actually moved my boot class to base package like "com.dbs.ntb.remittance". But then this application is specific to event logging batch. So I felt it is correct to place this in "com.dbs.ntb.remittance.eventlog.batch". It is referring to some entities in another module in "com.dbs.ntb.remittance.eventlog".